# Pentaho Data Integration - Meta Data Injection - Stream Lookup - 'RETRIEVE_DEFAULT_TYPE'

Tags: metadata, code-injection, pdi

I am new to Pentaho and using Pentaho Data Integration 9.3, I am trying to use ETL Metadata Injection for "Stream lookup" step.

I am however facing the below error when trying to pass the data type for the retrieved fields from the lookup stream:
2023/08/03 07:40:29 - ETL metadata injection.0 - ERROR (version 9.3.0.0-428, build 9.3.0.0-428 from 2022-04-12 04.56.25 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2023/08/03 07:40:29 - ETL metadata injection.0 - ERROR (version 9.3.0.0-428, build 9.3.0.0-428 from 2022-04-12 04.56.25 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException:
2023/08/03 07:40:29 - ETL metadata injection.0 - Error inject property 'RETRIEVE_DEFAULT_TYPE' into class org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.streamlookup.StreamLookupMeta
2023/08/03 07:40:29 - ETL metadata injection.0 - For input string: "Integer"
2023/08/03 07:40:29 - ETL metadata injection.0 -

I have tried multiple ways to provide this value, but nothing is working.

Please help.

I tried skipping passing the data type, but the final transformation is not working as per requirement without the data type defined for the retrieved lookup columns.